# How to remove a financial type from profile is already created and data is submitted?

Tags: civicontribute, profile

By mistake I have included a financial type while creating a profile which should not have selected. Now if I go to settings of profile now its disabled. How can I get it enable again? or a way to remove irrelevant financial type Please? [image: screenshot is here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your question but I think it is one of the following:

1. The *[x]CiviContribute* option in the screenshot above is automatically checked if you add a profile to a Contribution page. If you remove the profile from all Contribution pages, that option will disappear again.
2. If you want to remove a particular field from the Profile (e.g. if you added the "Financial Type" field to this profile), click on **View or Edit Fields for this Profile** in the screenshot above and look for that field to disable or remove it.

Comment: Thank you!! I am talking about the point 1. I understand now.